# Continuous Integration(CI):MonDB version is too low in the MAVEN project with Jmeter

Tags: mongodb, maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have a problem in my 'MAVEN project' when it tries to access mongodb with authentication:

> 500 - javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.mongodb.MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, [C) values:...

The reason is the 'mongo-java-driver-2.11.3.jar' does not support 'SCRAM-SHA1',so i deleted it and in POM.XML joined the 'mongo-java-driver-2.13.3',but Jmeter Configuring automatically download the 'mongo-java-driver-2.11.3.jar' again:

[image]

[image]

How to solve the problem?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: changing dependency will not help: if you want to add a new Mongo jar,  specify it inside `jmeter-maven-plugin`, as explained here: https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-additional-libraries-to-the-classpath. The only thing I'm not sure about is whether it can *replace* existing jars, never tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Exclude existing MongoDB Java Driver like:

   ```
   <excludedArtifacts>
       <artifact>org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver</artifact>
   </excludedArtifacts>
   ```
2. Include new version of the MongoDB Java Driver like:

   ```
   <testPlanLibraries>
       <artifact>org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.13.3</artifact>
   </testPlanLibraries>
   ```

Full *pom.xml* just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.blazemeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.blazemeter.jmeter.maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <testPlanLibraries>
                        <artifact>org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.4.2</artifact>
                    </testPlanLibraries>
                    <excludedArtifacts>
                        <artifact>org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver</artifact>
                    </excludedArtifacts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

References:

- [Adding jar's to the /lib directory](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-additional-libraries-to-the-classpath#adding-jars-to-the-lib-directory)
- [Fixing Conflicts](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-additional-libraries-to-the-classpath#fixing-conflicts)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)